# Excel formula: If one thing, give answer; else, give one of two possible answers

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I need a formula that will see if the cell contains the words "Daily" or "Weekly" and display a "0", and for anything else, it will check for the presence or absence of a date.

Comment: Are the only values in the cell to be tested going to be `Daily`, `Weekly`, a date, or nothing at all?

Comment: Unless something changes drastically, yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first attempt. I assumed rather than checking specifically for a date, we can just check to see whether or not the cell is blank.

If so, I think this can be accomplished by using a nested `IF` formula. First we will check for the words "Daily" or "Weekly" then we will check that the cell is non-black.

Assuming the cell we want to check is `A1`, we can use this formula:

```
=IF(OR(A1="Daily",A1="Weekly"),0,IF(A1<>"",1,0))
```

The first `IF` statement checks for "Daily" or "Weekly" in cell `A1` and populates whatever cell the formula is in with a 0 if either of those words are in cell `A1`. If cell `A1` does not contain those words the next step is to check whether or not it is blank. If the cell is not blank (e.g. there is a date) a 1 is returned, otherwise a 0 is returned.

Comment: Soulfire, you're a certified genius. That works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! If it's not too much trouble and you want to tick the green check mark to accept this answer I'd appreciate it. The points help people to know that I have at least some idea what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`

```
IF(OR(A1="", A1="DAILY", A1="Weekly", NOT(ISNUMBER(DATEVALUE(A1)))),0,1)
```

`

Remember to format Col A as "Text" data type

Comment: This seems to display a "0" no matter what's in the column. Sorry! No worries, though.